# how to add contacts to System group: my contacts in android

Tags: android, contacts

This code is only insert new contact into All other contacts in "Display Options". 
I don't know how to add to System group: my contacts.

here my code:

```
//Add contact type
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "aa@gmail.com")
        .build());

//Add contact name
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, (!name.toLowerCase().equals("unavailable") && !name.equals("")) ? name : phoneNumber)
        .build());

//Add phone number
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, phoneType)
        .build());

//Add contact
context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

have any properties support for this solution?